# I write data to cnosdb through jdbc, and the data writing is successful, but the returned interface is not the number of rows but -1. What's going on?

Tags: java, jdbc, cnosdb

I write data to cnosdb through jdbc, and the data writing is successful, but the returned interface is not the number of rows but -1. What's going on?My code as follow:

step:

1. creat a database;

   ```
   boolean rs002 = stmt.execute("CREATE DATABASE tc_between WITH TTL '100000d';");
           assertFalse(rs002);
   ```
2. create table;

   ```
   boolean rs004 = stmt001.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS m2(f0 BIGINT UNSIGNED, f1 BIGINT, TAGS(t0, t1));");
           assertFalse(rs004);
   ```
3. insert data in tables;

   ```
           int rs005 = stmt001.executeUpdate("INSERT m2(TIME, t0, f0, t1, f1) VALUES(CAST (1672301798050000000 AS TIMESTAMP), 'Ig.UZ', 531136669299148225, 'nA4C3DH~B ', 9223372036854775807),(CAST (1672301798060000000 AS TIMESTAMP), '263356943', 1040920791041719924, '', -9223372036854775807),(CAST (1672301798070000000 AS TIMESTAMP), '1040920791041719924', 442061994865016078, 'gE1B7c.', 0);");
           System.out.println(rs005);
           int rs006 = stmt001.executeUpdate("INSERT m2(TIME, t0, f0, t1, f1) VALUES(CAST (3031647407609562138 AS TIMESTAMP), '1D75h', 4166390262642105876, '7ua', 0.0),(CAST (1079616064603730664 AS TIMESTAMP), '}', 7806435932478031652, 'EA26qy', 23.456), (CAST (263356943 AS TIMESTAMP), '0.6287658423307444', 5466573340614276155, ',JC51Fh', -23.456), (CAST (1742494251700243812 AS TIMESTAMP), '#f^uE1B7KruC7BFz', 196790207, 'aF', 0.123);");
           assertEquals(4, rs006);
           int rs007 = stmt001.executeUpdate("INSERT m2(TIME, t0, f0, t1, f1) VALUES(CAST (3584132160280509277 AS TIMESTAMP), '', 4132058214182166915, 'V*1lE/', -0.123);");
           assertEquals(1, rs007);
           ResultSet rs008 = stmt001.executeQuery("SELECT m2.f0 FROM m2 WHERE CAST(0 AS STRING) BETWEEN (CAST( starts_with(m2.t0, m2.t1) AS STRING)) AND (m2.t1);");
           rs008.next();
           System.out.println(rs008.getString(1));
           stmt001.close();
           conn001.close();
   ```

the logs as follow:

```
[ERROR]   AppTest.test_Jdbc_betweensql:66 expected:<4> but was:<-1>
```

and then check the cnosdb info, as follow:

```
log 2
```

```
tc_between ❯ select * from m2;
+-------------------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------+

| time                          | t0                  | t1         | f0                  | f1                   |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| 2025-03-20T18:10:51.700243812 | #f^uE1B7KruC7BFz    | aF         | 196790207           | 0                    |
| 2004-03-18T13:21:04.603730664 | }                   | EA26qy     | 7806435932478031652 | 23                   |
| 2066-01-25T12:16:47.609562138 | 1D75h               | 7ua        | 4166390262642105876 | 0                    |
| 2022-12-29T08:16:38.070       | 1040920791041719924 | gE1B7c.    | 442061994865016078  | 0                    |
| 1970-01-01T00:00:00.263356943 | 0.6287658423307444  | ,JC51Fh    | 5466573340614276155 | -23                  |
| 2022-12-29T08:16:38.050       | Ig.UZ               | nA4C3DH~B  | 531136669299148225  | 9223372036854775807  |
| 2022-12-29T08:16:38.060       | 263356943           |            | 1040920791041719924 | -9223372036854775807 |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------+
Query took 0.100 seconds.
```

Comment: for all we know, the data was already in the db, and duplicates are not allowed

Comment: Do you have autocommit turned on? Are you sure?

Comment: Did you check a database driver version?

Comment: @RomanC jdbc version: arrow-jdbc:10.0.1  flight-sql-jdbc-driver:10.0.1

Comment: @Stultuske before I insert data, the database was empty.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch autocommit was turned on by default, I never change it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently cnosdb-flight-sql is not fully implemented.